# Python regex is correct but returning None

Tags: python, regex

My Regex has to identify contact numbers from string. It is correct and i have tested it on my samples online, here are the examples of it https://regex101.com/r/Q2Z6fy/1. But when i run it in my python code. It returns none

Here is the code where it should correctly identify string as matching.

```py
import regex as re
txt = '+92 42 111-865-865'
rest = re.match("^(?:(?:\(\+92\)|\+92) (?:42|332)|0332) ?\d+(?:([ -])\d+(?:\1\d+)*)?$", txt)
print rest.groups()
```

Expected Result is String itself but the regex returns None.

Comment: `import regex as re` ? That's wrong.

Comment: Use `import re`.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy it is the same result even if i use import re.

Comment: @Austin import re also returns same result

Comment: Use a raw string literal when defining the regex or  use ``\\1`` instead of ``\1``. I suspect you want to print `rest.group()`, not `rest.groups()`. See [demo](https://rextester.com/FMVMB81607).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thankyou very much. I used rest.group() instead of rest.groups(). It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `re.findall()` instead of `re.match()`

use below code

```
import re

regex = r"(?:(?:\(\+92\)|\+92) (?:42|332)|0332) ?\d+(?:([ -])\d+(?:\1\d+)*)?"

test_str = ("+92 42 111-865-865\n"
            "(+92) 42 3256 0445\n"
            "03325138889\n"
            "0332 5138889\n"
            "+92 332 5138889\n"
            "+92 3325138889\n\n"
            "48358982872144\n"
            "100220100\n"
            "36470002")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        print(match.group(groupNum))
```

Comment: it returns empty list

Comment: you need to fix your regex pattern

Comment: @UmairRashid i have tested it on my inputs: https://regex101.com/r/Q2Z6fy/1.

Comment: @mohartechnology see my updated answer

Comment: thanks this is correct. I was using match.groups() instead of match.group()